# How to create time type double in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have view solution AS3 in have const:

```
var enddate:number = 1.35947521048E12;
```

and it show in swf is 29-Jan-2013 23:00.

i want create number like 1.35947521048E12 by custom date and time. Everybody help me.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, that's not a constant. It's a variable that can be changed, constants are created once and can not be modified at run time. Also, you're defining it as 'number' - This should be Number. AS3 is case sensitive.

If you're wanting to create a date, AS3 has a 'Date' class, which can be called like this:

```
        var date:Date = new Date();
```

You can then set the date using the value you've provided, like this:

```
        var date:Date = new Date();
        date.setTime(1.35947521048E12);

        trace(date);
        // Tue Jan 29 16:00:10 GMT+0000 2013
```

Or, if you just wanted to get the current system date/time, you'd just call:

```
        var date:Date = new Date();

        trace(date);
        // Sun Jul 13 13:44:56 GMT+0100 2014
```